# How to Convert Spark RDD from groupByKey to R DataFrame

Tags: python, r, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using the Spark pipe() function to pass rows of data that have been grouped by key (with groupByKey) to an R script that runs a hierarchical model on the data and spits out strings of data.

However, the grouped Spark RDD has a lot of filler structure to it and I have to do a lot of parsing to get it into an R DataFrame.

Here's the Spark code that munges my earlier data into what's going in the pipe():

```
.map(lambda p: (p.split(",")[0], ",".join(p.split(",")[1:len(p.split(","))])+"EOL" )) \
    .groupByKey().mapValues(list) \
```

Here's what the Spark structure looks like going through the pipe()

```
(u'1-10-13-8', [u'83845,"srd",-79.6376432430279,38.6874999965503,0.82,0,2013,NA,7,1,1,1,1174.88703492269,4,0,0,0,0,94.4444444444444,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.55555555555556,0,0,NAEOL', u'83845,"srd",-79.6376432430279,38.6874999965503,0.84,0,2013,NA,7,1,1,1,1174.88703492269,4,0,0,0,0,94.4444444444444,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.55555555555556,0,0,NAEOL', u'73437,"srd",-75.5229630639942,39.8124999964486,0.84,0,2013,NA,7,1,1,1,107.637711535396,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11.1111111111111,0,0,8.33333333333333,80.5555555555556,0,NAEOL'])
```

In R, I want to parse the key to one value and the remaining rows to a DataFrame. Both my Spark code and my R code have quite a bit of ugly munging (e.g., using EOL replacement) to get it into shape.

Here's the R code to parse this Spark structure coming into the R script.

```
 cbpos <- gregexpr(pattern='(\\[)', currentLine)
 currentText <- substr(currentLine, cbpos[[1]][1]+1, nchar(currentLine)-2)
 currentK <- substr(currentLine, 2, cbpos[[1]][1]-3)
 currentKclean <- substr(currentK, 3, nchar(currentK)-1)

 currentTextRead <- gsub("u'", "", currentText)
 currentTextRead <- gsub("'", "", currentTextRead)
 currentTextRead <- gsub("EOL, ", "\n", currentTextRead)
 currentTextRead <- gsub("EOL", "", currentTextRead)

 con <- textConnection(currentTextRead)
 currentValue <- read.csv(con, header=FALSE)
 close(con)
```

Is there a more efficient way to get the grouped data into R more naturally?

Would all of this be easier with SparkDataFrame? Or is there an easier way to have R reference the Spark data structure by key?

Comment: why not use `sparkR` ?

Comment: Have already tried and performance is terrible for the scale of the problem we're dealing with.

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is why Spark? If Spark is must have why `pipe`? If pipe why not use a well defined format as an output (JSON would be a huge improvement)? If `pipe` doesn't serve a deeper purpose they why not RPy or OpenCPU? If Spark is not must have why not some pipeline / worfklow management tool? Anyway... Quick and dirty solution: Throw away all the string concatenation, write `list` of records to a `tempfile` using `csv` or `pandas`, call R subprocess, read the output :)